# iterate lines containing zeros in bash

Tags: bash, replace

I am having a file which looks like this:

```
141.519
141.009
140.121
135.519
0
0
0
0
```

I'm writing a shell script and I want to replace all lines containing a zero with -1e+10.

So far, I’ve tried this:

```
while read a 
do
    if [ "$a" == "0" ]; then
        echo ${a//0/-1e+10}
        #let a="-1e+10"
    fi      
done < $name.pitch.f0.ascii  > $name.pitch.f0.ascii.replaced  ;
```

but as a result, all lines are replaced with -1e+10. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `echo ${a//0/-1e+10}`, `echo "-1e+10"` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is missing `else echo "$a"`. You don't have to use a loop, though: Use `sed` which processes the file line by line:

```
sed -i~ -e 's/^0$/-1e+10/' $name.putch.f0.ascii
```

`-i~` creates a backup with the `~` extension.

`s///` means "substitute". `^` matches a line start, `$` matches a line end.

Answer (score 1):

using awk:

```
awk '{if($0==0){print "-1e+10"}else{print $0}}' file
```

output:

```
141.519
141.009
140.121
135.519
-1e+10
-1e+10
-1e+10
-1e+10
```

In the above code if line only contain `0` it will replace with -1e+10 else print the line as original

simply: suggested by muru

```
awk '$0 == 0 {$0 = "-1e+10"}1' file
```

Comment: Concisely: `awk '$0 == 0 {$0 = "-1e+10"}1'`

Comment: yep one can do that too :) (y), let me update that too

Comment: Assuming no blank lines `awk '!$0{$0="-1e+10"}1'`